# Mysql Duplicate Rows ( Duplicate detected using 2 columns )

Tags: mysql, sql

How to remove duplicated in this setup?

```
id    A       B 
----------------
1     apple   2  
2     orange  1       
3     apple   2   
4     apple   1
```

In here I want to remove (apple,2) which occurs twice. The id numbers are unique. I would use DISTINCT keyword if it were not. Can I some how make a key out of columns A and B and then use the DISTINCT keyword on that to get what I need ? Many thanks for your replies.

Comment: Thank you all for the replies again. I think I have a good idea now how to proceed.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
delete from myTable 
where id not in
(select min(id)
from myTable
group by A, B)
```

i.e. the select in brackets returns the first id for each grouping of A and B; deleting all ids that are not in this set will remove all occurences of an A-plus-B combination that are "subsequent" to its first occurrence.

**EDIT**: this syntax seems to be problematic: see bug report:

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=5037

A possible workaround is to do this:

```
delete from myTable 
where id not in
(
      select minid from 
      (select min(id) as minid from myTable group by A, B) as newtable
)
```

Comment: How does this perform relative to my answer below?  I'm not enough of a DB guru to analyze it...

Comment: Nice.. 
this will remove row where id=3 and not where id in 1,3

Comment: @Benjamin: I'm not sure: my guess is that it will depend on the data distribution. But this version should be portable to other databases and for me - at least! - it's more readable.

Comment: Definitely more readable - glad to hear it's more portable as well.  I'll be testing this out next week on my own data set.  Thanks, Dave!

Comment: I get this error when using this construct. I can always use a temp table ofcourse. 

ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'myTable' for update in FROM clause.

Comment: @Senthil: you're right: DELETE has a problem with inline subqueries referring to the target table. See my edited comment.

Comment: why are you using min fn in subquery .Without min fn same result is there.

Answer (score 6):

Yet another (from http://labs.creativecommons.org/2010/01/12/removing-duplicate-rows-in-mysql/). Add a unique index then delete it:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE mytable ADD UNIQUE INDEX tmpindex (A,B);
ALTER TABLE mytable DROP INDEX tmpindex;
```

The `IGNORE` keyword is a mysql extension that makes it drop rows that violate the `UNIQUE` keyword instead of just failing.

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE FROM fruit_table FT1
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT * FROM fruit_table FT2 
    WHERE FT2.fruit_name_column = FT1.fruit_name_column
    AND   FT2.fruit_integer_column = FT1.fruit_integer_column
    AND   FT2.id <> FT1.id
)
```

This assumes you don't care which of the duplicate records is removed.

Comment: Errors for me in MySQL - "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FT1"

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE
FROM mytable
USING mytable, mytable AS vtable
WHERE vtable.id > mytable.id
AND mytable.A = vtable.A
AND mytable.A = vtable.A
```

Comment: Errors for me in MySQL - "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'tbl USING..."

Answer (score 0):

You could use a temporary table with the data you want:

```
insert into temp_table
select min(id), A, B
 group by A, B
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking here.  If you don't want duplicates of the A and B columns, then do just what you mentioned `SELECT DISTINCT A, B FROM XXX`.  Maybe you could post an example of the type of result you would like to see.

Comment: I guess "group by" is what I was missing, the other posts have clarified this.