# Removing duplicates in MySQL irrespective of column in which the data appears

Tags: mysql

I have a question very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534034/removing-bidirectional-duplicates-in-mysql).

I have a table like so:

Character1      Character2      Age1        Age2        Species     Residence
Donald              Daisy                82        76            Duck       Duck pond
Daisy               Donald              76        82              Duck          Duck pond
Donald              Daisy                     82         76               Duck        Duck swamp
Mickey               Minnie                  88          88             Mouse     Mouse hole

The rows 1 and 2 are duplicates except for the fact that the values for Character1 & Character2 and Age1 & Age2 are swapped. I want to remove one of these instance and leave the other instance. 
To achieve this:

Character1      Character2      Age1        Age2        Species     Residence
Donald              Daisy                82        76            Duck       Duck pond
Donald              Daisy                     82         76               Duck        Duck swamp
Mickey               Minnie                  88          88             Mouse     Mouse hole

Comment: Go on. Try something.

Comment: @Strawberry The only solution that I can think of is to create a temporary table containing IDs for each of the characters, hence essentially reducing the problem to exactly the same as the other post I have mentioned. But I think there is a solution that can be achieved without the temporary table.

Comment: The first problem you have is that this design is flawed... and when you design tables poorly, problems pop up that are difficult.  Any time you have a table with more than one column of "thing" in a table (e.g. character1, character2) you have set yourself up for trouble.  Relationships like this require at least two tables, and if you had such a design, the solution would be more straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
( a CHAR(1) NOT NULL
, b CHAR(1) NOT NULL
, c CHAR(1) NOT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY(a,b,c)
);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('j','k','x'),
('k','j','x'),
('j','k','y'),
('l','m','x'),
('m','l','x'),
('m','l','z');
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.01 sec)

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+---+---+---+
| a | b | c |
+---+---+---+
| j | k | x |
| j | k | y |
| k | j | x |
| l | m | x |
| m | l | x |
| m | l | z |
+---+---+---+

SELECT p.* 
  FROM my_table p 
  JOIN my_table q 
    ON q.b = p.a 
   AND q.a = p.b
   AND q.c = p.c 
   AND p.a > q.a;
+---+---+---+
| a | b | c |
+---+---+---+
| k | j | x |
| m | l | x |
+---+---+---+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

DELETE p 
  FROM my_table p 
  JOIN my_table q 
    ON q.b = p.a 
   AND q.a = p.b
   AND q.c = p.c 
   AND p.a > q.a;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.01 sec)

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+---+---+---+
| a | b | c |
+---+---+---+
| j | k | x |
| j | k | y |
| l | m | x |
| m | l | z |
+---+---+---+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Strawberry !  Kindly could you explain to me the role of the last "AND p.a > q.a" in achieving the solution.

Comment: Especially considering the fact that the column "a" is not numeric.

Comment: 'k' is greater than 'j'

Comment: Got it, I didn't know that ">" could be used with characters too. Thanks again.