# MySQL delete from query where two columns are duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql

What I'm looking to do, is delete all duplicated where column A and column B are duplicate.  For example:

```
A      B      C   
-----------------
Apple  Pear   11  
Apple  Pear   12  
Apple  Pear   13  
Orange Apple  22  
Orange Beer   21  
Cinder Punch  30  
Cinder Punch  31  
Cinder Punch  32
```

Would result in:

```
A      B      C   
-----------------
Apple  Pear   11  
Orange Apple  22  
Orange Beer   21  
Cinder Punch  30
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799518/mysql-duplicate-rows-duplicate-detected-using-2-columns

Comment: @skaffman: There are countless duplicates -- do you not agree there should be a tag to make it easier to find them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1: Move the non duplicates (unique tuples) into a temporary table

```
CREATE TABLE new_table as
SELECT * FROM old_table WHERE 1 GROUP BY [column to remove duplicates by];
```

**HERE, [column to remove duplicates by] = column names seperated by "COMMA", so in your case A,B**

Step 2: delete delete the old table
We no longer need the table with all the duplicate entries, so drop it!

```
DROP TABLE old_table;
```

Step 3: rename the new_table to the name of the old_table

```
RENAME TABLE new_table TO old_table;
```

Comment: Won't work in this case, the problem is those two rows arent key rows and if I group them i'll end up having multiple rows still.  I'll make sure i change my question.

Comment: so you mean that A and B are seperate rows, and you have included some numbers as well, is that a third row ?

Comment: No A|B|C are all different columns.  I have to leave 1 row of matching A|B's regardless of C.

Comment: @Mike Edited answer to make it a solution for your updated problem.

Comment: can we do........select * from table group by [column to remove duplicates by]-- means not all columns .... my question is - can we select simply 'c' also without putting 'c' in group by clouse ??

Comment: @pratik I suppose you are asking to replace * with a column name (lets say c) and not putting 'c' in the [column to remove duplicates by], if so, YES you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

you can do as follow to achive this

```
delete from table_name
where rowid not in (select min(rowid) from table_name group by a,b)
```