# How to find duplicate rows based on multiple fields in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mysql Duplicate Rows ( Duplicate detected using 2 columns )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799518/mysql-duplicate-rows-duplicate-detected-using-2-columns)

In a MySQL database I have many rows. For example:

```
id | title   | time  | domain
32   title1    12:30   domain1.com
33   title1    12:30   domain2.com
34   title2    14:20   domain1.com
35   title3    14:30   domain2.com
36   title1    12:30   domain55.com
```

How am I able to select rows from a database based on **only** title and **time?** Duplicate domains or ID's are not of concern, only the other two fields.

I want to be able to retrieve rows 32, 33 and 36 because they have identical titles and identical times.

I don't want to have to put in a title or time, I want the query to return all fields where there's a "duplicate" match found on these two fields whether that be only two or 50. That way I can go through and edit or delete some of the duplicates.

Answer (score 66):

Here is what you want

```
SELECT title, time  
  FROM table
GROUP BY title, time
  HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Comment: it will skip next rows having title="title1" with time="10:00" cause grouping by the order of operation is SQL: 

    FROM clause
    WHERE clause
    GROUP BY clause
    HAVING clause
    SELECT clause
    ORDER BY claus

Answer (score 38):

```
select distinct id, title, time
  from table t1
 where exists (select * 
                 from table t2 
                where t2.id <> t1.id
                  and t2.title = t1.title
                  and t2.time = t1.time
               )
```

Comment: This actually answers the question, returning all three duplicate rows, whereas the [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12691631/283991) only returns one row.