# need to query from data from the database

Tags: mysql

I want to retrieve duplicates for all column 1 2 and 3 and 4

What I have is this [query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ii8TF.png)

But that is not the result i want i just want this [query 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIOHE.png)

I want to retrieve same name, same dob but different fname

This is what i have in my code :

```
SELECT * 
  FROM demo WHERE (name, dob) in 
    (SELECT name, dob
       FROM demo 
     GROUP BY name, dob 
       HAVING count(*) > 1) 
ORDER BY name ASC
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find duplicate rows based on multiple fields in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12691327/how-to-find-duplicate-rows-based-on-multiple-fields-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

This query is based on self join, when it joins this table it will iterate each record and compare with it. Based on question requirement, I have made conditions and if it finds same "name" and "dob" with different "fname", it will be in the last result.

```
select a.* from TestStack a, TestStack b where a.name = b.name 
and a.dob = b.dob and a.fname <> b.fname
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.