# Delete two-column duplicates from two tables, one column on each table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, duplicates, sql-delete

I have a tricky query that I need help with, I wonder if it is possible to do it without creating a temporary table. Here's the deal.

I have two tables that contain informations on the same entity. One contains identifiers and the other contains literal labels about a product. They are joined using their id column.

Table 1:

```
id    A       B 
----------------
1     12345   5  
2     123456  3       
3     12345   8   
4     12345   4
```

Table 2:

```
id    C       D 
----------------
1     cable   d  
2     iphone  c       
3     cable   b   
4     brick   a
```

What I am trying to achieve is deleting duplicates that have similar columns **`1`.`A`** and **`2`.`C`** in order to get something like this:

Table 1:

```
id    A       B 
----------------
1     12345   5  
2     123456  3       
4     12345   4
```

Table 2:

```
id    C       D 
----------------
1     cable   d  
2     iphone  c       
4     brick   a
```

As you can see, the problem is that as soon as I'll have deleted an item from one of the tables, I will no longer be able to identify the duplicate on the other.

Should I resign to create a temporary referential table, or would there be an awesome way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure from you example how you are deciding if things are duplicates there (I can't see anything other than the id that links the rows deleted in you example), but you can delete from multiple tables at once.

For example if you wanted to delete from both tables if the ids matched and the value of A in table 1 matched the value of C in table 2:-

```
DELETE Table1, Table2 
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 
ON Table1.id = Table2.id
AND Table1.A = Table2.C
```

EDIT - making an assumption that you want to keep the first one and delete others then something like this should do the job:-

```
DELETE T1b, T2b
FROM Table1 T1a
INNER JOIN Table1 T1b
ON T1a.A = T1b.A
AND T1a.id < T1b.id
INNER JOIN Table2 T2a
ON T1a.id = T2a.id
INNER JOIN Table2 T2b
ON T1b.id = T2b.id
AND T2a.C = T2b.C
```

Comment: I am trying to remove duplicates that have the same id in both table, and similar column in their respective tables, such as there: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1799518/1439597 except in my case, these two columns are on different tables.

Comment: So how do you decide which of the duplicates to remove? Ie, for Table 1 you have 3 rows with the value of A being 12345, so why are id 1  and id 4 kept, and why is id 3 chosen to be deleted? Or is it because cols C also match? In which case why is 1 kept and 3 deleted? Is it just because 1 has the smaller ID?