# How to add Composite Primary Key and remove duplicates on existing table?

Tags: mysql

I have a very simple table called favorites with two columns user and content. How do I add a composite primary key on these columns and remove all duplicates (eg. same content AND user value)

```
ALTER TABLE favorites
ADD PRIMARY KEY (user,content)
```

Gives errors like #1062 - Duplicate entry '24-26885' for key 'PRIMARY'

Answer (score 0):

1st you remove the duplicates row like [Mysql Duplicate Rows ( Duplicate detected using 2 columns )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799518/mysql-duplicate-rows-duplicate-detected-using-2-columns) and then create the composite primary key

Answer (score 0):

The question is old, but a simple solution may still help someone facing this issue.
The way around the error '*Duplicate entry xxx for key PRIMARY*' is to use REPLACE instead of INSERT on the table dump. That way the latest record for a particular index will be kept.

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted. 
>   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html

Step 1. Create SQL dump file for you table

Step 2. Modify the dump file in the following way:

- add primary key (or UNIQUE index) to the table definition
- use **REPLACE INTO** instead of **INSERT INTO** (all instances must be changed)

Step 3. Appy the changed dump file to your DB