# Django: How to delete duplicate rows based on 2 columns?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I found out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1799535/2255491) I can easily delete duplicate rows (duplication based on N columns) in a table with raw SQL.

Is there an equivalence using Django ORM ?
The only stuff I found in Django concerned duplicated based on 1 column only.

Note : I know there is a way to prevent future duplicates (based on several fields) in Django, using `unique_together` field (but I didn't know before).

Thanks.

Comment: May you show your some of rows and columns of table?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A direct translation from the SQL in the other answer into Django ORM:

```
from django.db.models import Min
# First select the min ids
min_id_objects = MyModel.objects.values('A', 'B').annotate(minid=Min('id'))
min_ids = [obj['minid'] for obj in min_id_objects]
# Now delete 
MyModel.objects.exclude(id__in=min_ids).delete()
```

This will results in 2 separate SQL queries instead of the one nested SQL provided in the other answer. But I think this is good enough.

Comment: If you have default ordering for your model, make sure to remove it by putting .order_by() at the end: min_id_objects = MyModel.objects.values('A', 'B').annotate(minid=Min('id')).order_by().  Otherwise, your default order field will appear in the GROUP BY clause of the query, which could mean you miss duplicates.

Comment: @neowang It seems that this query could be a problem with a large MyModel dataset and just few dups, because the WHERE/IN clause created by the exclude can be huge.

Comment: One caveat that I found is that if you want to delete the first object that was created and not the last object that was created, use `max` instead of `min` here.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an [`RunSQL` `operation`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/migration-operations/#runsql) with the SQL that removes duplicates in one of your migrations, before the operation that adds the uniqueness constraint.

A remark: if you are using `sqlmigrate`, `RunSQL` has an advantage of including its SQL into the resulting migration SQL.

Comment: I actually already added the uniqueness constraint (before deleting duplicates) and and applied migration.

Comment: You can delete everything from the DB, delete migrations from the point where you added it, add the `RunSQL`  and recreate the migrations (I am assuming it is not in production).